# What is the area of canvas required to make a conical surface tent with height $35~\text{m}$ and radius of base $84~\text{m}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> A conical circus tent is to be made of canvas. The height of the tent is $35~\text{m}$ and the radius of the base is $84~\text{m}$. What is the area of canvas required?

I calculated slant height which came out to be $76.3$ and then I applied lateral surface area of cone formula which is $\frac{22}7\times76.3\times84$
 But my answer is wrong. Right answer is $24024$.

This a gmat exam question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you calculated the slant height, but it can't be right since slant height must be greater than radius. Use Pythagoras: $\ell^2=35^2+84^2$.

(edit: it looks like you calculated it as $\ell^2=84^2-35^2$, but if you draw a triangle with vertices the centre of the base, the apex, and a point on the circumference, it is the slant height which is the hypotenuse.)

Answer (score 1):

The slant height is $a=\sqrt{h^2+r^2}=91m$

$$S=\pi  r a \approx 3.14\cdot 84 \cdot 91\approx 24024m^2$$